# Center <div> problems HTML

Tags: html, css, width, margin

I have a problem. I am trying to make simple HTML-based website. I want to make the image and the white fields "full" the screen (width 100%) but it is somehow limited from both sides with some sort of margin. I am a fresh webguy so probably the solution is simple but so far I cannot find it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>ARSPOLSKA</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styl.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 
 
<!-- ========= HEADER ========= -->

<div class="belka-menu">
 <div class="limiter">
 <div id="logo"></div>
 <p>TECHNICZNE ZAOPATRZENIE PRZEMYSŁU</p>
  <nav class="nawigacja">
 <ul>
        <li><a href="regulamin.php">REGULAMIN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">KATALOG PRODUKTÓW</a></li>
        <li><a href="promocje.php">PROMOCJE</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.adamscrew.cba.pl/wordpress">STRONA GŁÓWNA</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- ====== HEADER ====== -->



<!-- ====== SLIDER ====== -->
<div class="slider-imitation"></div>
<!-- ====== SLIDER ====== -->



<!-- ====== ZAWARTOSC ====== -->
  <div class="container-item">

   <div id="item">
    <div class="foto"><img src="http://www.adamscrew.cba.pl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/arspolska/img/img1.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="text">
     Jesteśmy firmą handlową zajmującą się obsługą i zaopatrzeniem oraz wsparciem technicznym dla
      działów utrzymania ruchu zakładów i firm. 
    </div>
   </div>
  
  
   <div id="item">
    <div class="foto"><img src="http://www.adamscrew.cba.pl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/arspolska/img/img4.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="text">
     Posiadamy zaplecze umożliwiające wykonanie prac związanych z obróbką, skrawaniem,
      pracami związanymi ze spawaniem oraz szeroko pojętymi usługami.
    </div>
   </div>
 
 
   <div id="item">
    <div class="foto"><img src="http://www.adamscrew.cba.pl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/arspolska/img/img3.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="text">
     Współpracujemy z największymi dystrybutorami dzięki  temu otrzymują Państwo produkty najwyższej jakości w 100% oryginalne.
    </div>
   </div>
  
  
   <div id="item">
    <div class="foto"><img src="http://www.adamscrew.cba.pl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/arspolska/img/img2.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="text">
     Jesteśmy w stanie dostosować się do potrzeb każdego przedsiębiorstwa.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
<!-- ====== ZAWARTOSC ====== -->
 
 
<!-- ====== STOPKA ====== -->
    <footer class="stopka">
  <div class="limiter"> 
   <div class="stopka-logo"></div>
   <div class="stopka-info">
    <h1>ARSPOLSKA Jóźkowicz i wspólnicy Sp. J.</h1>
    <p>ul. Przemysłowa 14B</p>
    <p>59-300 Lubin</p>
    <p>NIP 692-250-43-38</p>
   </div>

   <div class="stopka-info">
    <h1>KONTAKT</h1>
    <p>tel: 515 012 162</p>
    <p><b><a href="mailto:kontakt@arspolska.com" target="_top">kontakt@arspolska.com</a></b></p>

   </div>
   <div class="podstopka">Copyright © 2017 ARSPOLSKA Wszystkie prawa zastrzeżone.</div>
  </div>
    </footer>
<!-- ====== STOPKA ====== -->

</body>
</html>
```

```css
/* ====== GLOBALNE ====== */

@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url('../OpenSans.ttf'), url('../OpenSans.eot');
  /* IE */
}
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Times, serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #333;
}
#logo {
  background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
  background-size: 90px;
  height: 87px;
  width: 133px;
  z-index: 999999;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.limiter {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.slider-imitation {
  height: 586px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/1.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
/* ====== MENU ====== */

.belka-menu p {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #979797;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  position: absolute;
}
.belka-menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  border-top: 5px solid #f05928;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 90px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
/* ====== NAWIGACJA ====== */

.nawigacja li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  float: right;
}
.nawigacja li a {
  color: #979797;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.nawigacja li a:hover {
  color: #f05928;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: color 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* ====== STOPKA ====== */

.stopka {
  padding: 40px 0;
  color: #999;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  margin-top: 40px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: left;
  height: 200px;
}
.stopka-info {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 13px;
}
.stopka-logo {
  background-image: url('../img/logo.png');
  display: block;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.podstopka {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f05928;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
  color: #fff;
}
/*====== CONTAINER ======*/

.container-home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  clear: both;
}
.container-item {
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffff;
  clear: both;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
#item {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#item:hover {
  border: 2px solid #f05928;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: transform 4s;
}
.text {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}
.foto img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 220px;
  max-height: 220px;
}
.box {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set your body margin. By default your browser has some margins (8px on Chrome) so the content will not appear behind the scrollbar.

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Times, serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```